# Simple Recipe for Guitar-Piano Duo

Tags: guitar, piano, electric-bass-guitar, accompaniment

I would like together with a friend and play songs together. I play both the piano and guitar, and he only plays guitar. I tried it first by recording myself playing a pop song on the piano (only chords just to see how it would sound like) and then I tried to accompany it with guitar (both electric and acoustic). I found that playing the same chords doesn't really always work, so I searched the internet for advice and I found only one source. Thus I ask here for further information.

I imagine that the question is too broad and one might have to specify a genre. Hence, I formulate the 2 questions and you can answer to whichever you think makes more sense (or both).

1. Can you give some general notes-advice on how to accompany a piano with a guitar (or vice versa)?
2. Can you give some notes-advice on how to accompany a piano song with a guitar (or vice versa) on specific genres? (I am mostly interested in pop, ballads. You can add for other genres if you are more familiar with them. Other people might find it helpful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Piano plays Bass and rhythm chords (accompaniment) guitar is soloing (melody or improvisations)

b) Guitar plays rhythm chords (accompaniment), Piano plays Melody and Bass

this means the guitar is functioning as Solo-G. (a) or rhythm-G. (b)

c) the two instruments are playing in a dialogue: guitar is responding or playing fill-ins at the end of each piano phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule is ***"Stay out of each other's way"***

Some of the classic old 70's pop/country ballads do that quite simply, but I'm struggling to fill up an easy list that would give you a 'big picture' view.

<sup>preliminary, not final. will add detail…</sup>

Comment: Ugh - this is not really my style of music, but I have some 'recipes' in my head. Trouble is, after an hour scouring youtube, I can't find songs that fit, so I'm thinking of just losing this answer :\